# Apply function only on specific rows AND columns using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, lambda

I have a dataframe below:

```
df = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
      'b': [77, 88, 99],
      'c1': [1, 1, 1],
      'c2': [2, 2, 2],
      'c3': [3, 3, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

and a function:

```
def test_function(row):
    return row['b']
```

How can I apply this function on the 'c' columns (i.e. c1, c2 and c3), BUT only for specific rows whose 'a' value matches the 2nd character of the 'c' columns?

For example, for the first row, the value of 'a' is 1, so for the first row, I would like to apply this function on column 'c1'.

For the second row, the value of 'a' is 2, so for the second row, I would like to apply this function on column 'c2'. And so forth for the rest of the rows.

The desired end result should be:

```
df_final = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
            'b': [77, 88, 99],
            'c1': [77, 1, 1],
            'c2': [2, 88, 2],
            'c3': [3, 3, 99]}
df_final = pd.DataFrame(df_final)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with compare `c` columns filtered by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and if match repalce by values of `b`:

```
c_cols = df.filter(like='c').columns

def test_function(row):
    #for test integers from 0 to 9
    #m = c_cols.str[1].astype(int) == row['a']
    #for test integers from 0 to 100
    m = c_cols.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int) == row['a']
    row[c_cols] = row[c_cols].mask(m, row['b'])
    return row

df = df.apply(test_function, axis=1)
print (df)
   a   b  c1  c2  c3
0  1  77  77   2   3
1  2  88   1  88   3
2  3  99   1   2  99
```

Non loop faster alternative with broadcasting:

```
arr = c_cols.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).to_numpy()[:, None]
m = df['a'].to_numpy() == arr
df[c_cols] = df[c_cols].mask(m, df['b'], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael! I think it's nearly there but is it possible to make use of the "test_function" function? I tried using the .apply function but it's still giving me some error. I've updated the question too because of the assertion error. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @Alvin - In `c` columns are only integers `0 to 9` ? Answer was edited, can you check?

Comment: the integers in my actual data range from 1 to 100. The function works! Thanks a lot for your help :) I tried to for a for loop "for i in df['a']" but it didn't work. Didn't know I had to edit the function itself.

Comment: @Alvin - Solution was changed for match 1 to 100.